# How can I use a Wavebird with a PC?

Tags: pc, controllers

I want to emulate games, but I have a [Wavebird Wireless controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WaveBird_Wireless_Controller) with no receiver. Is there an adapter or can I make one? I want it to go to USB.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can see this working is to get a [gamecube controller adapter for PC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000RLWF7I) and use the Wavebird wireless receiver with the adapter.

There is absolutely no native support for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Okay. I'll just try that.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are willing to open it up and modify it to suit a usb fm reciever to work with your custom fm controller insert (which you'd have to build also...) there is no way.